# Boostrap modal update with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where a generate buttons that have data-id in them. When i click on the button a send the data-id through ajax to my php code, open modal window and generate content with recieved id. But the problem is that i need to refresh the page first to even get some value inside $_POST variable, and after i open and close my modal, i need to refresh page again so my variables update and doesnt open same window.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Otevre modal
  $('.show-modal').click(function(){
    var product_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: {modalID : product_id},
      url: 'includes/getID.php', // tomuto souboru predas idecko produktu, zapises do kosiku atd.
      success: function(data) {
        $("#itemBox").modal('show');
        // treba nejaka hlaska, ze byl pridan do kosiku
      }
    });

    // kod co otevre modal, mkrni na bootstrap manual jak je otevira nebo si otevreni nadefinuj sa
    //$('.product_id').val(productID);
  });
});
```

**Here is JS code,**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}


if(isset($_REQUEST['modalID'])){

    $_SESSION['modalBoxID'] = $_REQUEST['modalID'];
}
?>
```

Here is how i am saving the requested ID from ajax.

and here is how i generate my modal boxes, the problem is that without refreshing page, every box that i open have same content in it.

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
session_start();
}


if(!isset($_SESSION['sessName'])){
$_SESSION['sessName'] = 'visitor';
}

if(!empty($_SESSION['modalBoxID'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE     vehicle.id='{$_SESSION['modalBoxID']}'";
$sqlquery = $db->query($sql);
$_SESSION['modalBoxID'] = NULL;
}
?>


<div class="container">

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="itemBox" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">


      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body display-content">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <?php while($details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)) : ?>


            <div class="col-md-4"><img src=<?php echo $details['image'];?> class="image-responsive">

              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <form action="add_cart.php" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity">
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <br/>
                <button type="button" class="add-to-basket btn btn-success" >ADD TO CART</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-7" id="desc">
              <p><b>Model:</b> <?php echo $details['model'];?></p>
              <p><b>Engine:</b>  <?php echo $details['engine'];?></p>
              <h4>Description</h4>
              <p><?php echo $details['description'];?></p>
              <hr>
              <hr>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Is this even possible with solution that i have ? I dont even get any content on first page load, i need to refresh it so my ID saves to variable and then it will show some content.

Comment: Is your `.show-modal` button and modal code are in same file ??

Answer (score 0):

Add below to your javascript. It removes the previous data from modal body. You might experience few some delay before the new content is loaded.

```
$(document.body).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $("#itemBox").removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: It removes the old data, but now my modal data wont generate

Comment: Are you not loading the modal content from a different file? Is the ' .show-modal ' class added to an anchor tag (<a>)?